# Minor-mode launched by a parent minor-mode

Tags: minor-mode

I want to have a minor-mode (tika) that launches another minor-mode (ramona).  How can such thing be handled?

The following is the child minor-mode

```
;; File: ramona.el (child)

(define-minor-mode ramona-minor-mode
  "Focused editing."
  :lighter " Ramona"

  (when ramona-minor-mode
    (message "Launch Ramona Tools.")
    (ramona-tools)) )
```

The following is the parent minor-mode

```
;; File: tika.el (parent)

(define-minor-mode tika-minor-mode
  "TODO."
  :lighter " Tika"

  (when tika-minor-mode
    (message "Launch Ramona Minor-Mode")))
```

Comment: Minor-modes come with their own hooks, just like major-modes.  "*... Hook run after entering or leaving `%s'....*"

Comment: How can I handle this?

Comment: By adding the child mode enablement function to the parent mode's hook. When the parent mode is then enabled, its hook will run and it will in turn enable the child mode.

Comment: Then I can have something like `(add-hook 'tika-mode-hook #'ramona-minor-mode)`.  How does one define hooks for minors?

Comment: See @lawlist's comment above.

Comment: Where should one introduce the hook?  Inside `(when tika-minor-mode` ?  I would also want to remove the hook when the parent mode is disabled.

Comment: `(add-hook 'tika-minor-mode-hook #'ramona-minor-mode)` should do it.